# Refrescar combobox a partir de DATALIST

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

Estoy actualizando **combobox** a partir de otro **combobox** y el siguiente a partir del segundo... se entiende?

Ej:

- TIPO
- MARCA
- MODELO
- PRECIO

El tema que todo barbaro... pero justo en MODELO lo hago aparecer con un DATALIST en vez de un Combobox, como para que se pueda buscar mas rápido... pero no se como hacer para que me actualice el siguiente combobox (Precio)

El código para hacerlo con Combobox es:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {
    $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function () {
        modelo = $(this).val();
        $.post("includes/getmodelo.php", { modelo: modelo }, function(data){
            $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
        });            
    });
  })
});
```

Puedo obtener el resultado del MODELO en el DATALIST pero no puedo refrescar al siguiente combo...Yo supongo que todo el problema esta en:

```
$("#cbx_modelo option:selected").each(function ()
```

ya que ahi aparece el 'opcion:selected' y creeria que pertenece a un COMBOBOX y no a un DATALIST...

Alguien me puede dar una mano para que actualice al siguiente combo??

El coligo completo seria:

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbx_tipo").change(function () {

      $('#cbx_marca').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="whatever"></option>').val('whatever');                   
        $("#cbx_tipo option:selected").each(function () {
        tipo_articulo = $(this).val();
        $.post("includes/getmarca.php", { tipo_articulo: tipo_articulo }, function(data){
          $("#cbx_marca").html(data);
        });            
      });
    })
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {
      $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function () {
        modelo = $(this).val();
        $.post("includes/getmodelo.php", { modelo: modelo }, function(data){
          $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
        });            
      });
    })
  });
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbx_modelo").change(function () {
      $("#cbx_modelo option:selected").each(function () {
        lista = $(this).val();
        $.post("includes/getprecio.php", { lista: lista }, function(data){
          $("#cbx_precio").html(data);
        });            
      });
    })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

si el problema tiene que ver con el query que haces para recorrer los `options` ya que no esta soportada por Jquery te podría recomendar una forma de hacerlo

```
.
..
...
....
var tipos = $("#cbx_tipo").selectedOptions;
for(tipo of tipos){
   tipo_articulo = tipo.value;
   $.post("includes/getmarca.php", { tipo_articulo: tipo_articulo }, function(data){
     $("#cbx_marca").html(data);
   }); 
}
....
...
..
.
```

espero te sirva.